# Javascript template literal strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, templates, literals

Why is the following code syntactically correct?

```
let v = ``(oldVal-newVal) / 1000;
```

It gives the following runtime error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: "" is not a function
```

My guess is the `` becomes a tagged template, and "" would be tag name, but not sure.
(I got to this by accidentally typing it instead of the Ctrl+` shortcut in VSCode. Took a day to find it. ;)

Comment: it's just an empty string

Comment: You'd get the same behaviour if you do `""()` or `5()` or whatever. You're trying to execute that value. Which is not executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tagged template takes the form:

```
function myTaggedTemplate(...) { }
```

And is called with:

```
myTaggedTemplate`...`
```

You have a variable name referencing a function on the left, and a template string on the right.

---

What you have is equivalent to:

```
const left = ``;
left(oldVal-newVal);
```

It errors with "is not a function" because it is a string, not a function.

It is syntactically valid because you can try to treat the result of any expression as a function. Determining if it is a function or not happens at run-time.